# Adding a new column for the amount of rows within the last month

Tags: python, pandas

Let's start with a pandas dataframe as so:

```
>>> df
     Date
0    2006-01-30
1    2006-02-02
2    2006-02-03
3    2006-02-04
4    2006-02-21
5    2006-02-23
6    2006-03-07
7    2006-03-11
8    2006-04-24
9    2006-04-25
```

I would like to add a new column which is the amount of dates that are within the previous month of the date on that row, as so: (Does that make sense?)

For a date '2006-02-23' I would like the number of dates between '2006-01-23' and '2006-02-22

```
>>> df
     Date          Past_Month
0    2006-01-30    0
1    2006-02-02    1
2    2006-02-03    2
3    2006-02-04    3
4    2006-02-21    4
5    2006-02-23    5
6    2006-03-07    2
7    2006-03-11    3
8    2006-04-24    0
9    2006-04-25    1
```

Right now I have it working with the below code but it runs slows for size of my data. What is a more efficient way to do this?

```
for i in range(len(df)):

    days = (df['Date'] >= df['Date'][i] + pd.DateOffset(months=-1)) 
        & (df['Date'] < df['Date'][i])

    df.loc[i,'Past_Month'] = days.sum()
```

Comment: Your output is conflicting or I am understanding it wrong, but accordingly, index 9 should also have value 3 right or index 5 should have 1 ?. As you said "amount of dates that are within the previous month"

Comment: Your expected output is confusing as @ShivamKotwalia said. Also why has index 6 amount 2? Arn't there 5 dates in month 2?

Comment: Tried to run your code on the sample, the 8th row is `0` instead of `2`.

Comment: @ShivamKotwalia Sorry everyone, I will rephrase. For a date `'2006-02-23'` I would like the number of dates between `'2006-01-23'` and `'2006-02-22'`

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try np's broadcast:

```
offset = df.Date + pd.DateOffset(months=-1)
df['Past_Month'] = np.sum((df.Date.values > offset.values[:,None]) 
                          & (df.Date.values < df.Date.values[:, None]),
                          axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    Date                   Past_Month
--  -------------------  ------------
 0  2006-01-30 00:00:00             0
 1  2006-02-02 00:00:00             1
 2  2006-02-03 00:00:00             2
 3  2006-02-04 00:00:00             3
 4  2006-02-21 00:00:00             4
 5  2006-02-23 00:00:00             5
 6  2006-03-07 00:00:00             2
 7  2006-03-11 00:00:00             3
 8  2006-04-24 00:00:00             0
 9  2006-04-25 00:00:00             1
```

This basically does what your code does but vectorized by `np`. What broadcast does is to take an array, and `duplicate` it along another dimension without using extra memory. Example:

```
ar = np.array([0,1,2,3])
ar

array([0, 1, 2, 3])

ar[:,None]

array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3]])

# then this compares every member of one array to every member of the other
ar < ar[:,None]

array([[False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False]])

# now you have that, then you do the sum in your code
np.sum(ar < ar[:,None], axis=1)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Would you be able to give a quick explanation how this works? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: `(df.Date.values > offset.values[:,None]) & (df.Date.values < df.Date.values[:, None])`just comes out to `array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False])` when I put it in.